# How to make test with UIInterfaceOrientation enum values

Tags: ios, bit-manipulation, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm a little bit lost in the bitwise ;)

My goal is to retrieve the whole set of orientations supported by an application and to test each result value to update a custom variable.
My problem is that I don't know how to make the comparison (I got a conversion/test problem...)

First I read this article : [Testing for bitwise Enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105655/testing-for-bitwise-enum-values)
But it doesn't bring me the light...

Let say I have the following orientation declare for my application (following is the log output for my variable *supportedOrientations*) :
supported orientations = (
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
)

So my first attempt was to try some test on integer values but it does not work (even if the application is declared to be in portrait mode the test return 'false') :

```
NSArray *supportedOrientations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];
NSLog(@"[supported orientations = %@", supportedOrientations);
// for clarity just make a test on the first orientation we found
if ((NSInteger)supportedOrientations[0] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
  NSLog(@"We detect Portrait mode!");
}
```

My second attempt was to try the *bitwise thing* but this time it always return 'true' (even if the supported orientation is not UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait). :

```
NSArray *supportedOrientations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];
NSLog(@"[supported orientations = %@", supportedOrientations);
// for clarity just make a test on the first orientation we found
if ((NSInteger)supportedOrientations[0] | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) { // <-- I also test with UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait but no more success
  NSLog(@"We detect Portrait mode!");
}
```

So my question is :

- How to test the orientation in my case?
- Is it a way to use a test by using a bitwise thing (using | operand)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official doc says that **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations** is an **array of strings**. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10

So the solution is to use NSString comparison for each element found in the array.

```
NSArray *supportedOrientations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];
for (NSString *orientation in supportedOrientations) {        
    if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait"] ||
        [orientation isEqualToString:@"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown"]) {
        NSLog(@"*** We detect Portrait mode!");
    } else if ([orientation isEqualToString:@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft"] ||
               [orientation isEqualToString:@"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"]) {
        NSLog(@"*** We detect Landscape mode!");
    }
}
```

Note that doing like this we didn't take advantage of the enum values (of type UIInterfaceOrientation), but it works!